# WebView with Flash on a 3.1 device with 2.2 app

Tags: android, flash, webview

I'm building an 2.2 and up version application.
This gives me some problems using a webView,
mainly because Flash won't work on a 3.1 device.

I have looked into this and the solution states that i should add :

```
android:hardwareAccelerated
```

in the Manifest.
or

```
 getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

in the code

however, since I am using android 2.2 to create the App, this is not possible. 
Would the only way to get this working be to create in 3.0 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should be able to do something like this in your manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

That'll set the application target to Android 3.0, so you can use the hardware acceleration tag in the manifest file, but allow the application to be installed on Android 2.2+.

Just make sure that you're only using API's available in Android 2.2.

Comment: It won't let me , i get this error on the manifest : 
No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'

Comment: Make sure that the target is set to API level 11. You probably need to change it in the project properties. The following works for me: `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

Comment: thanks , that worked. 
building on a lower version just gives me warnings but still works.